# Prestashop remove /presta on url

Tags: url, prestashop

As the title says, I want to remove the `/presta` from my URL.

I can access it now with `domain.com/presta` but if I change from `Preferences > SEO & URL > Base URL` as "/", I can't access the site and if I connect to admin panel it's without GUI, just text.

Seems a little bit confusing.

Thanks in advance, sorry for any newbie mistake I've been working on this the whole day and it's my first try on presta.

Answer (score 0):

i think all Prestashop files are inside a folder named "presta" instead of (for example) the httpdocs folder. Change shop domain and ssl domain to your domain name. Set base uri as / and press save. Now move all Prestashop files from the presta folder to the httpdocs folder. The presta folder should be empty, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**Current situation:**

You prestashop files are stored in **YOURSTORE/presta/**

**Request situation:**

removing the subfolder **/presta/** so people can enter the url **YOURSTORE/** to acces your prestashop webshop.

**What you must do:**

1. copy all your files inside **YOURSTORE/presta/** to **YOURSTORE**.
2. remove .htaccess (located here (after step 1): **YOURSTORE**).
3. Update your prestashop database: go to table *ps_shop_url* and change value:

*physical_uri -> /presta/*

To

*physical_uri -> /*

You should be able to enter your store now by visiting YOURSTORE.com instead of YOURSTORE.com/presta/